# Как сделать, чтобы при соприкосновении картинок менялсь переменная?

Tags: java, изображения, jframe

Есть 2D игра. Дело дошло до получения урона персонажем, и я столкнулся с проблемой касания двух картинок. Вот есть картинка img и img7, как сделать так, чтобы при их соприкосновении менялась переменная healthInteger.

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
JFrame frame;
private int sco = 0;
private long t = System.nanoTime();
Player player = new Player();
public Main(JFrame frame) {
    t1.start();
    this.frame = frame;
    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyPressed(e);
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            player.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
}
Timer t1 = new Timer(20, this);
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Image img = new ImageIcon("resources/testImage.png").getImage();
    Image img1 = new ImageIcon("resources/back.png").getImage();
    Image img3 = new ImageIcon("resources/as.png").getImage();
    Image img4 = new ImageIcon("resources/chest.png").getImage();
    Image img5 = new ImageIcon("resources/helth.png").getImage();

    g.drawImage(img1, player.getmapX(), player.getmapY(), 3476, 2168, null);
    g.drawImage(img, 263, 146, null);
    g.drawImage(img3, player.getBoxX(), player.getBoxY(), null);
    g.drawImage(img4, player.getChestX(), player.getChestY(), null);
    g.drawString("SCORE:" + sco, 10, 20);
    g.drawImage(img5, 10, 30, null);

    long tm = System.nanoTime() - t;
    double angle = tm/300000000.0;

    double sn = Math.sin(Math.sin(angle) * 0.3); 
    double cs = Math.cos(Math.cos(angle) * 0.3);
    int x = (int) (200 * sn + 150);
    int y = (int) (200 * cs + 150);

    int healthInteger = 100;

    Image img6 = new ImageIcon("resources/evil.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img6, x+ player.getmapX() + 800, y + player.getmapY() + 500, 40, 40, null);
    Image img7 = new ImageIcon("resources/evil.png").getImage();
    g.drawImage(img7, x+ player.getmapX() + 500, y + player.getmapY() + 500, 40, 40, null);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent action) {
    repaint();
    player.move();
}

}
```

Comment: Советую прочитать про хитбоксы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понимаю, изображения не вращаются, соответственно их можно представить в виде 2 прямоугольников. У класса awt.Rectangle есть встроенный метод для определения пересечений boolean intersects(Rectangle r) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html
Соответственно достаточно создать два прямоугольника для каждого из изображений, написав что-то вроде:

```
Rectangle imgRect = new Rectangle(263, 146, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
Rectangle img7Rect = new Rectangle(x+ player.getmapX() + 500, y + player.getmapY() + 500, 40, 40);
...
...
...
(В игровом цикле)
if(imgRect.intersects(img7Rect)) {
//ваша механика со здоровьем
}
```

Comment: Вы не совсем правильно поняли, но всё работает :)